# how to get tag value that wrapped in table?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<td> <label for="cp_designation">Designation : </label></td> 
                                    
                                   <td> PARTNER</td>
                                </tr>                        
                        <tr>   
                                    <td><label for="cp_category">Category : </label></td> 
                                
                                   <td>SPORTS GEARS</td>
                                </tr>
                        <tr>
                               <td> <label for="cp_address">Address : </label></td> 
                            
                               <td> A-148, WARD NO.4, PAINTER STREETSIALKOT-CANTT.</td>
                            </tr>
                        <tr>  
                               <td> <label for="cp_phone">Phone  : </label></td>
                            
                               <td> 4603886,</td>
                            </tr>
                            
soup = bs(page.content, "html.parser")
for i in soup:
  label = soup.find_all('label',text='Designation : ')
  print(label.find('tr'))
```

hi y'all my question is that i want to extract label value that is in  tag i tried so many things but fail to get value. did you guys has any experties if yes so it would be hightly appreciatable. thanks in advance.

Comment: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-2aba6c078f44> in <module>()
      2 for i in soup:
      3   label = soup.find_all('label',text='Company Name : ')
----> 4   print(label.find('tr'))

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/bs4/element.py in __getattr__(self, key)
   1882     def __getattr__(self, key):
   1883         raise AttributeError(
-> 1884             "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
1885

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find main `tr` tag with `find_all` method to iterate over `label` tag to get data as `key-value` pair and use `find_next` to get next tag with `label` tag to get values of labels

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
dict1={}
for i in soup.find_all("tr"):
    label=i.find("label")
    dict1[label.get_text(strip=True)]=label.find_next("td").get_text(strip=True)
```

Output:

```
{'Designation :': 'PARTNER',
 'Category :': 'SPORTS GEARS',
 'Address :': 'A-148, WARD NO.4, PAINTER STREETSIALKOT-CANTT.',
 'Phone  :': '4603886,'}
```

Comment: but i have 10k plus tags in page.

Comment: can you share URL if possible

Comment: https://scci.com.pk/members-directory/ this is page put a and hit on search. the view button is contain information

Comment: To collect more data, you'd move the dictionary into the for loop and add it to a list.

Comment: can you please help? @Samt94

Comment: I forgot to convert to dictionary, I've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

What we do here is take a list of the headers, take a list of the table rows, and zip the headers to the data stored in the table data tag (as text), we then convert this to a dictionary and add to a list.

This isn't the best way of scraping as you can hit issues where data doesn't exist and data in the incorrect location, however with the below you can adapt it to be more robust.

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

all_data = []

table = soup.find('table')
headers = [i.text for i in table.find_all('th')]
rows = table.find_all('tr')

for row in rows:
    table_data_text = [i.text for i in row.find_all('td')]
    output_dict = dict(zip(headers, table_data_text))
    all_data.append(output_dict)
```